# Showing numbers from port gets an error

Tags: python, arduino, decode

I am trying to decode data of 8-bits (or 1 byte) from an external source (an Arduino) and convert them into numbers using Python.

This is the code I am using:

```
arduinoData = serial.Serial("com4", 9600)

while True:
  if arduinoData.inWaiting()>0:
    print "Reading data"
    arduinoString = arduinoData.read(arduinoData.inWaiting())
    ardString= int(arduinoString, 2)

    for string in ardString:
        print string
  else:
    print "There is no data"
```

Using this, I can open the port and read data sent by the Arduino.

When I build this, I get this error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\`

I have tried to decode the data with a lot of variations, but I can not get the numbers that I need. How can I convert this data?

Hope you can help me.

### ------- EDIT --------

I managed to get binary numbers (i hope) using this lines:

```
while True:
  if arduinoData.inWaiting()>0:
    print "Leyendo datos"
    arduinoString = arduinoData.read(arduinoData.inWaiting())

    ardString = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in arduinoString)

    for string in ardString:
        string = int(ardString, 10)

        print string
```

And this lines gives me this error:

`string = int(ardString, 2)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 '`

Are these binaries right? I tried to convert them into integers as you can see above, but it gaves me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ord` is all you need, it will produce an `int` and then you're done.

```
bytes = map(ord, arduinoString)
for byte in bytes:
    print byte
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does these lines give me integers? Or do i have to convert str into int later?

Comment: `ord` converts a character to an `int`. Your code was converting the ints back into strings and then trying to get ints again. So yes, that's it. `bytes` is a list of `int`s. But also you shouldn't ask me if it works, try it for yourself! Play around with the code and the `ord` function in the python shell. For example `print map(ord, '\x01\x01')` will show you `[1, 1]`.

Comment: I was asking because i was not at home and i cuold not try it. I did not ask you if it works. Thank you a lot, this solved the problem.